# Tridion Where Used window showing "only old version" in comment column

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-manager, where-used

Few binaries are still referencing old versions of components. What does old version mean here and how to remove these old versions from Tridion? Please suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to clarify to understand.

For example **Binary Multimedia component A** used in **Content schema Component B** in version 1 later that component updated to changed to use a different image then it becomes version 2. In this case, **Binary Multimedia component A** still used in **Content schema Component B** as an Only old version of 1.

In this case, you can go to **Content Component B** history and remove those old versions.

I hope it helps